# Android Studio Watch Expression persistence

Tags: debugging, android-studio

Android Studio removes all my watch expressions after each debug.
How can I force it to keep my watches and save them in project?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do save watches that I know of.  However you can use "Auto-Variables-Mode" (bottom left debugger tab >> settings button).  This will clean up some of the less desired variables in the debugger variables window, then hopefully you'll need less watches.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that variables entered when not in debugging mode are lost since the interface cannot figure out the statements when they are not compiled and running.

Hopefully you have the same problem as me and starting debugging before entering your variables fixes it.